# How to proxy_pass to a sub path

Tags: nginx

I have a host with two containers:

- nginx
- check_mk

the check_mk interface is accessible by http://172.17.0.2:5000/cmk
I have proxy_pass rule set up in nginx:

```
server {                                                                  
    listen 80;                                                            
    server_name cmk.domain.com;                                     
    location / {                                                          
        proxy_pass         http://172.17.0.2:5000;                        
        proxy_redirect     off;                                           
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;                                    
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                        
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;                 
    }                                                                     
}
```

When I hit the nginx on port 80 with `cmk.domain.com/cmk` it works.

What I want is that when hitting the server_name `cmk.domain.com`, the `/cmk` would be added automatically.
I tried doing  `proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.2:5000/cmk;` but then I get a page not found error.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the corresponding entries in the access and error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cmk.domain.com;

    location /cmk {
        proxy_pass         http://172.17.0.2:5000;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://cmk.domain.com/cmk$request_uri;
    }
}
```